# Java "Given final block not properly padded" Exception in Tomcat5.5 Server

Tags: java, tomcat, encryption

I'm having problem with decoding an encrypted text.
When the encrypted message is received, Java would sometimes throw an exception below.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_h.b(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_h.b(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_af.b(DashoA12275)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA12275)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA12275)
    at com.inv.my.encrypt.StringEncrypter.decrypt(StringEncrypter.java:206)
    at com.inv.my.encrypt.EncryptDecryptMachine.decrypt(EncryptDecryptMachine.java:56)
    at com.inv.my.servlet.transfer.hq.RequestStockQty.doPost(RequestStockQty.java:47)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$0(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:171)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

---

My server setup is...

1. Ubuntu 8.04 LTS
2. Java 5
3. Tomcat5.5

Weirdly enough the problem is intermittent. After restarting the server, it would go away but would come back later again which I would restart my tomcat again just to temporarily fix it.

Thanks!

---

Edit-Add Code:

The code I use is from...

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/java/security/java_cryptography_extension/StringEncrypter.java

and modified it a bit, below is my actual code. I removed the comments to make it shorter.

Thanks!

```
public class StringEncrypter {
Cipher ecipher;
Cipher dcipher;


public StringEncrypter(SecretKey key, String algorithm) {
    try {
        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchPaddingException");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchAlgorithmException");
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeyException");
    }
}



public StringEncrypter(String passPhrase) {

    setPassPhrase( passPhrase );

}


public void setPassPhrase( String passPhrase ) {

    // 8-bytes Salt
    byte[] salt = {
        (byte)0xA9, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0x32,
        (byte)0x56, (byte)0x34, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x03
    };

    // Iteration count
    int iterationCount = 19;

    try {

        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
        SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
        dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

        // Prepare the parameters to the cipthers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidAlgorithmParameterException");
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeySpecException");
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchPaddingException");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: NoSuchAlgorithmException");
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        System.out.println("EXCEPTION: InvalidKeyException");
    }
}


public String encrypt(String str) {
    try {
        // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");

        // Encrypt
        byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

        // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
        return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}



public String decrypt(String str) {

    try {

        // Decode base64 to get bytes
        byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
        System.out.println( "[decrypt]BASE64Decoded????? " + dec );
        System.out.println( "[decrypt]Algo: " + dcipher.getAlgorithm() );
        System.out.println( "[decrypt]Block Size: " + dcipher.getBlockSize() );
        System.out.println( "[decrypt]Parameters: " + dcipher.getParameters().getEncoded() );

        // Decrypt
        byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

        // Decode using utf-8
        return new String(utf8, "UTF8");

    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

---

Edit-Added Debugging Log

```
Encrypted: HS/uG4F/TZEN/lzX4xGvEQ==
[decrypt]BASE64Decoded????? [B@18df65f
[decrypt]Algo: PBEWithMD5AndDES
[decrypt]Block Size: 8
[decrypt]Parameters: [B@1139ac8
```

---

Better Logging Data

```
Encrypted: HS/uG4F/TZEN/lzX4xGvEQ==
[decrypt]BASE64Decoded????? [B@11b7a20
[decrypt]BASE64Decoded String??? 1D 2F EE 1B 81 7F 4D 91 0D FE 5C D7 E3 11 AF 11 
[decrypt]BASE64Decoded Length: 16
[decrypt]Algo: PBEWithMD5AndDES
[decrypt]Block Size: 8
[decrypt]Parameters: 30 0D 04 08 A9 9B C8 32 56 34 E3 03 02 01 13 
[decrypt]After decryption:68 71 53 69 64 5F 37 36 39 
Decrypted: hqSid_769
```

---

Added more logging after synchronizing function

```
Request data: hqSid_3443
[encrypt] String??? 68 71 53 69 64 5F 33 34 34 33
[encrypt] Encrypted??? C7 02 03 2D BD F9 A6 6A 93 C0 40 48 2E 5F 2B E5
[encrypt]Encrypted ï¿½-ï¿½ï¿½jï¿½ï¿½@H._+ï¿½
[encrypt]Encrypted Length 16
[encrypt]Algo: PBEWithMD5AndDES
[encrypt]Block Size: 8
[encrypt]Parameters: [B@f5cbda
```

---

received

```
Encrypted: xwIDLb35pmqTwEBILl8r5Q==
[decrypt]BASE64Decoded????? [B@13cd5ba
[decrypt]BASE64Decoded String??? C7 02 03 2D BD F9 A6 6A 93 C0 40 48 2E 5F 2B E5
[decrypt]BASE64Decoded Length: 16
[decrypt]Algo: PBEWithMD5AndDES
[decrypt]Block Size: 8
[decrypt]dcipher.Parameters().getEncoded(): 30 0D 04 08 A9 9B C8 32 56 34 E3 03 02 01 13
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded...
```

Comment: Can you show us some code ? What encryption do you use?

Comment: look here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872/given-final-block-not-properly-padded

Comment: Code added as requested.

Comment: I'm rather new to cryptography and I'm still trying to understand the link posted by ditkin.
What I'm still trying to get is why restarting my tomcat fix it? =/

Comment: @Jeff what is the debugging output you get when you run your code (both encrypt and decrypt)?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz  I Added the debugging log for the decryption above...
After the last log... it returns NULL, which I think is logical since an exception was thrown =/

Encryption doesn't have any logs, since it didnt fail... what do have in mind that I will log on the encryption side?

Comment: Both your base64decoded and "parameters" values are byte arrays. Can you fix the code to expand those and write-out the byte values? It looks like @ditkin is suggesting that you simply have the wrong decryption key. Is that possible?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz updated logs above, thanks! :)
P.s.: The newer log is the successful one.. as of the moment, I have not captured any exception logs, gonna have to do some waiting game agian :(

Comment: This code is not thread-safe. Is that a possible problem, here? What does your driver code look like? Also, instrument the 'encrypt' operation and show that output.

Comment: I made the function synchronized ( thread safe ) and ill see if this fixes anything but i doubt it since only one app is sending the encrypted data to the decrypter :/

Comment: little update.. so far no exceptions... could i have been wrong with the threading? =/

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz bad news.. didnt work.. still got the error..updated the logs above...

Comment: also, im reading around to try BouncyCastle APIs.... hope that would help...

Comment: Using BC probably won't change anything. But, if you re-write all your code you may fix the bug without knowing why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is definitely not threadsafe, and it appears to be the problem. You will need to use a different Cipher object for each thread.

Comment: Hmmm... not sure about the password since I stored the password/salt in our mysql database... ill try to log it if the password was retrieved properly..

Comment: FWIW, a constant salt isn't really a salt. You should use a random salt and store it with the hashed password.

Comment: wow... so far so good.. whole day no exception...
What happened before was that I placed the class above inside a Singleton so that I can reuse it over again....
I changed it so that every call it creates a new object of the class above... =/

Comment: Looks like my comment about threadsafety was probably the read problem: you can't share a Cipher instance across threads or nothing will work properly because all threads will use the same cipher objects and create chaos. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I will do more testing but this made good progress ^_^
One question though, anywhere I can look into more about cryptography and best practices?

Comment: That's a fairly open-ended question. Go to the library or a bookstore and browse the crypto section looking for things that appear to meet your needs. As for best coding practices: unless a class claims that it (or subclasses of it) are thread-safe, you certainly don't want to try to share them amongst threads without synchronizing access. Ciphers aren't that heavyweight anyway, so sharing one between threads doesn't really buy you anything -- it just makes things worse as you've seen.