# Exception: "Given final block not properly padded" in Linux, but it works in Windows

Tags: java, encryption

My application works in windows, but fails in Linux with `Given final block not properly padded` exception.

Configuration:

- JDK Version: 1.6
- Windows : version 7
- Linux : CentOS 5.8 64bit

My code is below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class SecurityKey {
    private static Key key = null;
    private static String encode = "UTF-8";
    private static String cipherKey = "DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";

    static  {
        try {
            KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
            String seedStr = "test";
            generator.init(new SecureRandom(seedStr.getBytes()));
            key = generator.generateKey();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }

    // SecurityKey.decodeKey("password")
    public static String decodeKey(String str) throws Exception  {
        if(str == null)
            return str;

        Cipher cipher = null;
        byte[] raw = null;
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        String result = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherKey);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        raw = decoder.decodeBuffer(str);
        byte[] stringBytes = null;
        stringBytes = cipher.doFinal(raw); // Exception!!!!
        result = new String(stringBytes, encode);

        return result;
    }
}
```

At the line:

```
   ciper.doFilnal(raw);
```

the following exception is thrown:

```
   javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I hope you don't care about security. Both DES and ECB, are a dubious choice.

Comment: You're assuming that `SecureRandom` behaves the same way on all platforms. Does java guarantee that? Use a KDF to derive a key, and not a PRNG.

Comment: Are you sure that `raw` contains the same data on both platforms? I'd suspect some wrong encoding coversion before passing the data to `decodeKey()`, though it's unlikely if you use base64.

Comment: Your error may be caused by a padding mismatch, of by an incorrect key.  You do not appear to specify the padding you expect on decoding.  Better to explicitly specify PKCS5.  Also don't use `sun.misc.*` as the library is not standard and not supported.  There are plenty of Base64 encoders/decoders around.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given final block not properly padded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872/given-final-block-not-properly-padded)

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the fact that `SecureRandom` seeding may be different for specific runtimes. Most of the time you will get `"SHA1PRNG"`, which won't get seeded immediately. Instead, you can call `setSeed()` before requesting any random, and in that case that seed is used as only source of entropy. In this case your key will always be the same.

The problem is that it is not defined which `SecureRandom` is returned. You may get an entirely different, platform specific implementation for which the above is not true. You may not get the one of the Sun provider, if another provider takes precedence.

Then there is the issue with the seed. The seed used the platform default encoding for the `seedStr` variable during the call to `getBytes()`. As the encodings may differ, the seeds may differ and thus the result will differ as well.

Try to use a function such as PBKDF2 instead for key derivation; there is enough on stackoverflow on how to procede.

Comment: Anybody there? Did this help? Did you solve your issue? Please report back!

Comment: Great that this solved your problem, it would be nice if you would accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As follows: I had to modify the contents.

```
static{
    try {
    KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    String seedStr = "test";
    SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    random.setSeed(seedStr.getBytes());
    generator.init(random);
    key = generator.generateKey();
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

}

It work's!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Fantastic, but don't come complaining when the random number generator actually generates random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Error it seems because of the encoded data , BASE64Decoder will return multiples of 4 and the Cipher is expecting multiples of 8.