# Encoding cypher broken in URL

Tags: java, tomcat, encryption, encoding, struts2

I've got a email verification system that sends an encrypted link for the user to click. I had one user tell me it wasn't working and I found a very strange error that I can't explain.

This is a local URL which works fine

```
http://localhost/cypher.action?cypher=TphMFuv%2FwcsgLThnU5cWInJFaZPMHeDFFL%2FRRPbbV70%3D
```

This is the remote URL which doesn't work

```
http://remotehost/cypher.action?cypher=TphMFuv%2FwcsgLThnU5cWInJFaZPMHeDFFL%2FRRPbbV70%3D
```

My application is running struts2 on a tomcat server but I don't think that matters. On the remote request the variable cypher is null. I can't understand why. It's running the exact same code

Cheers

Kris

**UPDATE**

Turns out that bad logging was hiding the real problem. The issue is that on the server it is getting a BadPaddingException

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
at service.DesEncrypterService.decrypt(DesEncrypterService.java:80)
at action.LoginAction.cypherLogin(LoginAction.java:93)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

Now to find out why that is happening on the server and not locally

**UPDATE**

It seems that it is a similar issue as this person is having
[Exception: "Given final block not properly padded" in Linux, but it works in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509363/exception-given-final-block-not-properly-padded-in-linux-but-it-works-in-win)

Some encoding difference on Linux?

Comment: Is your `remotehost` address really pointing at the server?

Comment: yeah it goes directly to my tomcat server. It works for the vast majority of cyphers. The problem is when there is a special character. like 9TOfCNEeycQM3tAsIyRtox8fAlLNYu+o is encoded to TOfCNEeycQM3tAsIyRtox8fAlLNYu%2Bo which also doesn't work because of the +. I don't understand why it works locally but the variable cypher is null on the remote machine

Comment: This is another example that when sent returns null g6EIaeFZHmUWTBqUUzeADQeZGcDaeWms. I played with it a little by removing some characters. This works g6EIaeFZHmUWTBqUUzeADQeZGcDae but then this is returned as null g6EIaeFZHmUWTBqUUzeADQeZGcDaeW. Why the heck would a 'W' effect it?

Comment: Compare your server.xml's URIEncoding setting.  It seems likely that it's set differently between  your servers.

Comment: Both look to be exactly the same
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

Comment: A "Bad Padding" exception can be caused by mismatched keys, so you need to check that the keys are byte by byte identical, not char by char due to decoding differences.  Also check that the decoding end is expecting the same padding as is being sent.  Don't rely on defaults, but set it explicitly at both ends.  Defaults can vary between systems.

Comment: @rossum I origianlly generated my key with KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES").generateKey();. I then serialized the key. I uploaded it to my server. The application when run locally or on the server de-serializes the key on load so that the results will always be the same. Do you think that it could be some slight difference in the serialized key that causes this issue sometimes?

Comment: @Kris: Check the keys byte by byte.  Serializing/de-serializing may not be exact across servers.  E.g. Java sometimes chews up bytes > 0x7F by turning them negative with unexpected results.

Comment: @rossum I just printed out the bytes on both machines and yes they are slightly different. How can I correct this? The server is running Linux and my dev machine is Windows. Will I need to serialize a new key on the Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

Your keys are different on the two machines.  You need to trace through the key processing on both machines so you can pinpoint where the differences are being generated.  Always check for byte-to-byte matching; character matching can be deceptive.  For example, end-of-line can differ invisibly between different systems.

First check that what is received after transmission is **exactly** what was sent.  Then put in byte dumps to logs after every piece of processing on the serialized key/parameters.  Do this on both home and away machines and compare.  That will pinpoint where the change happens from "same on both machines" to "different between machines".  That should pinpoint the method or code section where the problem is happening.  Repeat the byte dumps inside that piece of code until you have the problem isolated.  Again, you will need to dump on both machines so you have a known target from the home machine to compare against.

Comment: thinking about it does it matter that the keys are different? The server is the machine that sends the emails with the encrypted link and it's the server that is receiving the request to decrypt the link, so it is always using the same key. So shouldn't that be ok? Or is it that the key got screwed up some place that I should generate a new one on the server

Answer (score 0):

Do an URL encoding of the cyphered key before setting it. That will avoid adding extra characters.