# Exception: “Given final block not properly padded” in Linux, but it works in Windows

Tags: java, encryption

This can be a duplicate of [Exception: "Given final block not properly padded" in Linux, but it works in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509363/exception-given-final-block-not-properly-padded-in-linux-but-it-works-in-win) but not entirely.

My application works in windows, but fails in Linux with

> Given final block not properly padded exception

Configuration:

JDK Version: **1.8u162**

Windows : **version 10**

Linux : **OpenSuSE 42.2 (x86_64)**

My code is below:

```
public static Cipher createCipher(int mode, String passPhrase) throws CypherException {
        // Salt value
        byte[] salt = new byte[128]; // Should be atleast 8 bytes
        SecureRandom secRandom = new SecureRandom(passPhrase.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        secRandom.nextBytes(salt); // Self-seeded randomizer for salt

        // Iteration count
        int iterationCount = 12288;

        int derivedKeyLength = 256 ; // Should be atleast longer than 112 bits. Depends on Key size of algorithm.

        Cipher cipher;
        try {
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount, derivedKeyLength * 8);
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(APBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256).generateSecret(keySpec);

            byte iv[] = new byte[16];
            secRandom.nextBytes(iv); // Self-seeded randomizer to generate IV
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv) ; // IvParameterSpec initialized using its own randomizer

            // Note: there is no typical transformation string. Algorithm, mode (CBC) and padding scheme (PKCS5Padding) is all taken care by ALGORITHM_NAME.
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(PBEWithHmacSHA512AndAES_256);
            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount, ivSpec);

            // Create the Cipher
            cipher.init(mode, key, paramSpec);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
            throw new CypherException("No such Padding: " + nspe.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            throw new CypherException("Algorithm not supported: " + nsae.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
            throw new CypherException("Invalid key: " + ike.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException ikse) {
            throw new CypherException("Invalid key specification: " + ikse.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
            throw new CypherException("Invalid algorithm parameter: " + iape.getMessage());
        }
        return cipher;
    }

public static void decrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out, String passPhrase) throws IOException, CypherException {
        // Bytes read from in will be decrypted
        in = new CipherInputStream(in, createCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, passPhrase));
        int numRead;
        // Buffer used to transport the bytes from one stream to another
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        // Read in the decrypted bytes and write the cleartext to out
        try {
            while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, numRead);
            }
        } finally {
           // close the streams
        }
    }
```

And I am getting

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly
>   padded

at following line:

```
while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
```

Now, as suggested in [Exception: "Given final block not properly padded" in Linux, but it works in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509363/exception-given-final-block-not-properly-padded-in-linux-but-it-works-in-win) by Maarten Bodewes I am already using PBKDF2 as PBEWith*, really is the PBKDF2 + encryption scheme (CBC mode with PKCS5Padding). So why the encryption done on Windows doesn't work on Linux in my case? Can someone help please?

Comment: Perhaps the last bytes were never written to the file. Always remember to `close()` your file streams.

Comment: One of two things: The decryption failed so the padding is not a legal value or a different padding method was used. To determine which decrypt with no padding so there is no error. Then examine the result to see if the decryption was correct, if so examine the last block for the actual padding.

Comment: @zaph: Padding is taken care by algorithm name, I guess. This is as per Javadoc, so I expect this should work in platform-independent manner. Can you elaborate more on your second part? I didn't get that. How can I examine last block for actual padding?

Comment: The padding can be specified to by used can be specified to the encryption implementation. Specify no padding and the decryption will not get a padding error, the last block will just be decrypted. Then examine the last block in hexadecimal and you will be able to see the padding bytes. The most common padding is [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) (often misstated as PKCS#5), no padding and sometimes null padding.