# TrippleDES without base 64 encoding: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: encryption, encoding, tripledes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt a string using TrippleDES algorythm and without using Base64 encoding (my app will be talking to another app that has these requirements). Everything worked beautifully when I was testing stuff using Base64 encoding/decoding, but when I switched to doing it plain-text style (like the app I'm calling requires), everything broke.

I've read this post [Given final block not properly padded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872/given-final-block-not-properly-padded) which says the key is wrong on decoding, but that can't be, because these lines actually pass in the same variables for both the key and transformation:

```
ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
```

Also, I've printed out the lengths of both the encoded string and the array, their lengths are multiples of 8.

My output with I'm getting:

```
originalText: Abcdefgh
number of bites: 16
cryptText: d4167d9e2b3b1b2d1f940bc45099da0a
cryptText.length: 32
cryptText.getBytes().length: 32
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)
Java Result: 1
```

My full code (slightly modified version of this tutorial http://eternusuk.blogspot.com/2008/09/java-triple-des-example.html):

```
package com.test.encrypt;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class TrippleDESTest
{
    private Cipher ecipher;
    private Cipher dcipher;
    private String algorithm = "DESede";
    private String transformation = "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private String keyPhrase = "123456789012345678901234"; //your keyphrase 24 bit
    private SecretKey key;
    private IvParameterSpec iv;
    private static TrippleDESTest cryptoUtil;
    private String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    public static TrippleDESTest getInstance() throws Exception
    {
        if (cryptoUtil == null)
        {
            cryptoUtil = new TrippleDESTest();
        }

        return cryptoUtil;
    }

    private TrippleDESTest() throws Exception
    {
            DESedeKeySpec keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyPhrase.getBytes());
            key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm).generateSecret(keySpec);
            iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    }

    public String encrypt(String str) throws Exception
    {
            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes(ENCODING);    
            byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);                
            System.out.println("number of bites: " + enc.length);    
            return Hex.encodeHexString(enc);
    }

    public String decrypt(String str) throws Exception
    {
            byte[] dec = str.getBytes();
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);    
            return Hex.encodeHexString(utf8);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        TrippleDESTest test = TrippleDESTest.getInstance();        
        String originalText = "Abcdefgh";        
        System.out.println("originalText: " + originalText);        
        String cryptText = test.encrypt(originalText);        
        System.out.println("cryptText: " + cryptText);        
        System.out.println("cryptText.length: " + cryptText.length());
        System.out.println("cryptText.getBytes().length: " + cryptText.getBytes().length);        
        System.out.println("decote text: " + test.decrypt(cryptText));

    }
}// end class TrippleDESTest
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing the hexadecimal encoding in the wrong order. You need to decode the ciphertext, instead of encoding the plain text in your `decrypt` method.

Comment: @Creature glad it worked. Note that triple is spelled with a single "p", even though it does not sound that way.