# exception while decrypting a String

Tags: java, encryption, padding

I have been trying to encrypt with the Cipher class for a while now and I'm still getting issues. I'm having problems with the padding and with the byte array size. I receive this exception
"Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher"
This is the code I wrote:

```
public CipherClass() {
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGO);
        secKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGO).generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(new BigInteger(KEY, 16).toByteArray()));
    }
    catch(GeneralSecurityException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String encrypt(String text){
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        Base64 encoder = new Base64();
        return new String(encoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes())));
    }
    catch(GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

private String decrypt(String text) {
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey);
        Base64 decoder = new Base64();
        return new String(decoder.decode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes())));
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

I also tried using Hex instead of Base64 and I'm receiving this exception:
"Given final block not properly padded"

please help me out, to find error. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872/given-final-block-not-properly-padded

Comment: I did a class to encrypt/decrypt strings last year just as you did. For reasons I don't remember I had to get the text bytes in UTF-8 format. Try modify your last line like `return new String(encoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))));`

Comment: You need to run the base64 decoder before you decrypt.  The operations need to mirror each other: `encrypted = encrypt(plaintext) `, `encodedAndEncrypted = encode(encrypted)`; `encrypted = decode(encodedAndEncrypted)`, `plaintext = decrypt(encrypted)`

Comment: wow Zim-Zam thanks you fixed everything :)

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot So post it as an answer so it can be accepted. Now you had me read through all this just to find out it has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the base64 decoder before you decrypt. The operations need to mirror each other: `encrypted = encrypt(plaintext)`, `encoded = encode(encrypted)`; `encrypted = decode(encoded)`, `plaintext = decrypt(encrypted)`