# Spring Security Crypto Module - BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption, spring-security

I was trying to make an crypto util, I want to encrypt string, save in db then decrypt, I'm using TextEncryptor queryable spring security crypto module, because I want to use for rest apiKey , but i can`t make it work.

Here is my code:

```
        import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
        import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor;
        import org.springframework.security.crypto.keygen.KeyGenerators;

        public class CryptoUtil {

            public static String encrypt(String plain, String password) {
                String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey();
                TextEncryptor textEncryptor = Encryptors.queryableText(password, salt);
                return textEncryptor.encrypt(plain);
            }

            public static String decrypt(String encrypted, String password) {
                String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey();
                TextEncryptor textEncryptor = Encryptors.queryableText(password, salt);
                return textEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);
            }
        }

    ----------------------------------------------------    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "password";
        String plain = "hello";

        String encrypted = CryptoUtil.encrypt(plain,password);`enter code here`
        String decrypted = CryptoUtil.decrypt(encrypted, password);
    }

    ----------------------------------------------------

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to invoke Cipher due to bad padding
            at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.doFinal(CipherUtils.java:142)
            at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.AesBytesEncryptor.decrypt(AesBytesEncryptor.java:128)
            at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.HexEncodingTextEncryptor.decrypt(HexEncodingTextEncryptor.java:40)
            at com.ind.app.util.CryptoUtil.decrypt(CryptoUtil.java:18)
            at com.ind.app.Test.main(UsuarioTest.java:11)
            Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
                at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)
                at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
                at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
                at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
                at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.CipherUtils.doFinal(CipherUtils.java:135)
                ... 4 more
```

Comment: I guess you are running into this: [stackoverflow: Given final block not properly padded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872/given-final-block-not-properly-padded)

Comment: I think is the same exception, but not same case. I think the docs explain about queryable, because I want the same encrypted for a given texto. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-security-crypto-encryption-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone with this same problem:

> **String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey();**

Every call to this line according the docs:

> Creates a StringKeyGenerator that hex-encodes SecureRandom keys of 8 bytes in length. The hex-encoded string is keyLength * 2 characters in length.

So the salt is random, for example:
*plain* : "hello"
*password* : "password"
*salt* : "e606bfd5cf9f198e"

*encrypted* : "60e0e953841ca708b74ac657735a2236076f0a614ec85548d163fadf91e2be8f"

Then, when I try to decrypt and get the plain, the method generates another (random) salt, so *TextEncryptor.decrypt(String encrypted)* can't decrypt correctly because the salt is not the same.

> **Encryptors.queryableText(CharSequence password, CharSequence salt)**
>
> Creates an encryptor for queryable text strings that uses standard
>   password-based encryption. Uses a 16-byte all-zero initialization
>   vector so encrypting the same data results in the same encryption
>   result. This is done to allow encrypted data to be queried against.
>   Encrypted text is hex-encoded.

CryptoUtil working for encrypt and decrypt plain Strings, ***not recommended for passwords***, but useful for api keys for example.

```
public class CryptoUtil {

private static final String salt = "e606bfd5cf9f198e"; //any random generated salt

        public static String encrypt(String plain, String password) {
            TextEncryptor textEncryptor = Encryptors.queryableText(password, salt);
            return textEncryptor.encrypt(plain);
        }

        public static String decrypt(String encrypted, String password) {
            TextEncryptor textEncryptor = Encryptors.queryableText(password, salt);
            return textEncryptor.decrypt(encrypted);
        }
    }
```