# Generate a signed apk - Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to publish my first app on Google Play and I encounter difficulties. 
Let me explain my problem to you:
My app compiles and I want to generate a signed apk...
That doesn't work with android studio `(Build--> generate signed budle/apk)` and I had the next error message:

```
erreur keytool : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sebla\Desktop\AndroidApp\jdk-11.0.1\bin\mykeystore.jks (Accès refusé)
```

Then, I succeeded in creating the keystore (via cmd):
`C:\Users\sebla\Desktop\AndroidApp\jdk-11.0.1\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore appkeystore.keystore -alias permisKey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

but now I got the following error message when generating the signed apk:

```
Something went wrong with the encryption tool: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:410)
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineGetKey(KeyStoreDelegator.java:96)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.KeystoreHelper.extractPrivateKey(KeystoreHelper.java:56)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.KeystoreHelper.getPrivateKey(KeystoreHelper.java:35)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:98)
    at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard$2.run(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:241)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:989)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore.implDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:399)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.PKCS12PBECipherCore$PBEWithSHA1AndDESede.engineDoFinal(PKCS12PBECipherCore.java:431)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:348)
    ... 20 more
------------------------------------
```

Some help would be much appreciated as I'm completely lost and frustrated not being able to publish my app.
Do I have any code to implement in manifest or gradle to remove that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given final block not properly padded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872/given-final-block-not-properly-padded)

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not a duplicate as I didn't write any code related to encryption. It's just I want generate a signed apk from Android Studio

Comment: You can create new keystore from Android Studio. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29621643/6168272. Once you use this keystore and publish your app to Play Store, keep it somewhere safe.

Comment: Ranjan, I tried this way but I had the following error:  erreur keytool : java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sebla\Desktop\AndroidApp\jdk-11.0.1\bin\appkeystore.keystore (Accès is denied)

Comment: A few things. (a) It looks like you are using quite strange place to put your `keystore.properties` and `mykeystore.jks` files. (b) It also seem that your compiler is expecting a `PKCS12`-type keystore, whereas *Android Studio* has normally used another default. (I know the new gradle whines about this, telling you to convert to pkcs12, but when I did that I got weird errors too. (c) Try to follow my [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230396/1147688).

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error message after [generating a keystore](https://docs.codemagic.io/code-signing/android-code-signing/#generating-a-keystore) and signing and publishing the APK with [Codemagic](https://docs.codemagic.io/code-signing/android-code-signing/#setting-up-android-code-signing-on-codemagic).

My issue is that the command to generate the keystore only asked for the password of the keystore, which was then applied to the key. I found this out explicitly opening the keystore and unlocking the key using [Keystore explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html).

Double check that (1) your key password is correct (not just keystore password) and (2) your key password is being used by gradle in codesinging correctly.

Comment: This was a great resource! Using Keystore explorer, I found out that somehow I had swapped which password was for the store and which was for the key.