# FileNotFound Error for old keystore when trying to sign APK

Tags: android-studio, apk, keystore, android-keystore, signed-apk

I go to build>generated signed bundle/apk and input all the information for my `keystore`. However I get an error caused by `java.io.FileNotFoundException` for a different `keystore` that I'm not currently using. How can I fix this?

Comment: do you get access denied?

Comment: no, just an error saying file not found for a completely different keystore.

Comment: have you tried "invalidate and restart"? Can you show the full log?

Comment: I just tried invalidate and restart and now it says "given final block not properly padded"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049872/given-final-block-not-properly-padded