# ktor with keystore.jks converted from PEM does not work

Tags: ssl, https, ktor

I want to use https on a server I am building but I can't get it to work when creating the embedded server producing this error:

`Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.`

I have used these command to convert the certificate from PEM to JKS:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out keystore.p12 -name “miAlias”`

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks`

And on the server I use this code to load the certificate, and start the server which is where the error occurs:

```
    val keyStoreFile = File("resources/keystore.jks")
    val keyStoreIn   = FileInputStream("resources/keystore.jks")
    val keyStorePass = "****".toCharArray()
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()) 
    keyStore.load(keyStoreIn, keyStorePass)

    log.debug("keystore=${KeyStore.getDefaultType()}")  // pkcs12
    log.debug("mialias=${keyStore.containsAlias("miAlias")}")  // true

    val environment = applicationEngineEnvironment {
        connector {
            port = config.httpPort
        }

        sslConnector(
            keyStore = keyStore,
            keyAlias = "miAlias",
            keyStorePassword = {"******".toCharArray()},
            privateKeyPassword = {"******".toCharArray()}
        ) {
            port=8443
            keyStorePath=keyStoreFile
        }

        module {
             ...
        }
    }

    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, environment).start(wait = true)
```

Any idea what is happening? Because I'm a little lost with what to do.
Thanks!

The server works fine without https but when it is included it does not work and the described error occurs:
`Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.`

[image]

Comment: You may find this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053459/13963150) helpful.

Comment: I have had to use the same key in keyStorePassword and privateKeyPassword and it connects fine.
Thank you.